# Handling Missing Values in HDF5

Tags: hdf5-format

Suppose you have a dataset with missing or "bad" values e.g.

```
X = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10000000}];
X = If[# < 0.1, "Bad", #] & /@ X;
```

Instead of "Bad" substitute the characters of choice: "", "NaN", "N/A","Missing[]", etc

when I try to save the data in HDF5 format, I get an error message:

```
Export["test4.h5", X]
```

[image]

Of course, one could re-code missing/bad values as some numeric value (e.g. -99999), but this would be non-standard.

What's the best way to handle the situation?

Comment: Would it really be non-standard? I'm pretty sure I've seen plenty of HDF files that specify an "error" or "data missing" value like this. Nothing I can point to right this second but I was almost sure there was a metadata specified in the HDF standard itself that describes what value should be taken as "no data". Apologies for the haziness. Perhaps a way to get around this is to have a second "qa" table with the same dimensions that has a 0 where bad data exists in your main table (which I have also seen - for instance, in the ESA's S5P satellite data)

Comment: Re-coding would not be a horrible solution.  But I felt sure that there would be a more elegant fix for what is a very common issue.  However, I haven't managed to track down any reference to missing values in the HDF5 documentation.